# ggplot2 geom_bar width to fill gaps

Tags: r, ggplot2

What I would like to achieve is similar to geom_area, but using geom_bar. The default width of the bars leave too much space between them. I essentially want zero space between the bars if that's what the data indicates. An example of this is **Plot 2** below. However, this results in overlapping bars and only works on Windows now. I'd like to achieve variable-width-bars where the data determines the width. In the case of my data, the x-axis is the date/time and I would like the width of the bars to come from the duration of the data collection interval (dur_m). So, a 60 minute bar would be 4 times the width of a 15 minute bar.

Here's what the data looks like:

```
WAIT_CLASS                 end SNAP_ID AVG_SESS dur_m barChartWidth
  User I/O 2015-03-04 16:59:00   46606    52.24    60          3780
       CPU 2015-03-04 16:59:00   46606    26.65    60          3780
  User I/O 2015-03-04 17:59:00   46607    48.78    60          3780
       CPU 2015-03-04 17:59:00   46607    25.48    60          3780
  User I/O 2015-03-04 18:13:00   46608    44.05    14           882
       CPU 2015-03-04 18:13:00   46608    29.31    14           882
```

- WAIT_CLASS=factor used for fill of stacked bars
- end=time/date when the data collection ended
- SNAP_ID=not important
- AVG_SESS=y-value
- dur_m=minutes of data collection period. end-dur_m=start
- barChartWidth=my previous hack that seems broken now on non-Windows
  platforms

Challenges / Notes:

- The data may span 8 hours or it may span 30 days (totally variable)
- The dur_m can change, even within the same data set
- Some data may be missing, like if they shut down the database for a few hours
- I had been "hacking" this, resulting in overlapping data warnings. This now throws an error on non-Windows platforms: "Error: Results must be all atomic, or all data frames". I never liked this hack anyway.

Reproducible example code including data pulled from github:

```
# Download 23 kb DF_AAS.Rda which contains one data.table
temporaryFile <- tempfile()
download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmuth/public-data/master/R/AAS-Bar-Plot/DF_AAS.Rda", 
              destfile = temporaryFile, method = "curl")
load(temporaryFile)

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(grid)

plot_aas_chart <- function(DF_AAS_INT,barWidth){

  aas_colors <- c("Administrative" = "#6c6e69", "Application" = "#bf2a05", "Cluster" = "#ccc4af", "Commit" = "#e36a05",
                  "Concurrency" = "#8a1b07","Configuration" = "#5a4611","CPU" = "#05cc04","Network" = "#9b9b7a",
                  "Other" = "#f06fad","Scheduler" = "#97f797","Queuing" = "#c4b69c",
                  "System I/O" = "#0993de","User I/O" = "#054ae1")
  gg_aas_colors <- scale_fill_manual("", values = aas_colors)

  plot_aas_wait_class <- ggplot()+
    geom_bar(data=DF_AAS_INT, aes(x = end, y = AVG_SESS,
           fill = WAIT_CLASS),stat = "identity", position = "stack",width=barWidth)+
    gg_aas_colors+
    theme(axis.title.x  = element_blank(),axis.title.y  = element_blank(),
          legend.key.size =    unit(0.6, "lines"))+
    labs(title=paste("Average Active Sessions (AAS) for DB...","",sep="")
    )
  return(plot_aas_wait_class)
}

plot_aas_chart(DF_AAS,NULL) 
plot_aas_chart(DF_AAS,4000) # barWith=4000
plot_aas_chart(subset(DF_AAS,SNAP_ID < 46614),NULL)  # filter down to 1 day
```

Output:
Plot 1 - NULL Width
[image: Plot 1, width is null]
Plot 2 - Width=4000
[image: Plot 2, width is 4000]
Plot 3 - data filtered to 1 day, Width=NULL
[image: Plot 3, width is null, 1 day of data]

Comment: I'm really unclear on what you're looking for. I don't see a question. I'm about 80% sure that the graphs you show are examples of your current state, not where you want to be, I'm not sure what you don't like about the 2nd graph. You say "I essentially want zero space between the bars if that's what the data indicates." How does the data indicate this? The only column that I see that might indicate that is `barCharWidth` but instead you say that's an now-broken old hack. (Maybe `dur_m`?) Your set-up is really nice and reproducible, I just don't understand your goal.

Comment: Re-reading your question, my guess is you want bar width to depend on `dur_m`. I don't think there is support for variable widths with `geom_bar`, but `geom_rect` should work just fine. [There's an example of stacked geom_rect here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19873763/903061).

Comment: @Gregor thank you for your patience. After re-reading it, my question was not clear. I've edited the question to try to clarify. You are correct in that Plot 2 is essentially what I was trying to achieve. However, it's not exact as it results in overlapping bars which only works on Windows now, not linux where this gets deployed. The code (not shown) to come up with the barWidth is ugly: `if(snapIntervalMode < 20){
    barChartWidthFudgeFactor <- 0.15
  }`

Comment: @Gregor I'll have a look at the stacked geom_rect example you linked to. If that works, I'll post the updated code back here. Thank you again.